# Add days to date when a select dropdown value is selected JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field where I have a date and what I want is to add to the date on `Date` field the number of days selected on `Limit` dropdown and show the result in the label. but I dont know how to do this:

**EG:**  `ReleaseDate` is '06-02-2019 16:19:01' if I select '15 days' the output should be: `06-17-2019`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#Limit').on('change', function () {
      
      var Limit = $(this).val();

       if(Limit=="0")
  {   
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 0 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="8")
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 8 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="15")
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 15 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="30")
  {
     document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 30 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="45")
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 45 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="60")
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 60 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else if(Limit=="90")
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML+="add 90 days to date on ExpDate";
  }
  else
  {
   document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date:';
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="col-lg-1">
    <label class="control-label" for="Name">Release Date </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" readonly id="Date" name="txtFecha" placeholder="Release Date" 
  value="02-06-2019 16:19:01" type="text">
</div>
 
  <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Name">Time Limit<span style="font-size: 150%;  color: red;">*</span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="Limit" name="cbmlimit" readonly required> 
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option value="0">0 days</option>
         <option value="8">8 days</option>
         <option value="15">15 days</option>
         <option value="30">30 days</option>
         <option value="45">45 days</option>
         <option value="60">60 days</option>
         <option value="90">90 days</option>
         </select>
         <label class="control-label" id="ExpDate" for="Name">Expiration Date:</label>
                            </div>
 </body> 
  
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for conditionals based off of what choice is selected. Below should be what you are looking for:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Limit').on('change', function () {
    var Limit = $(this).val();

    // Splits date into array of date components
    //    [day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds]
    var value = $('#Date').attr("value").split(new RegExp('[-+()*/:? ]', 'g'))

    var d = 
    {
     day: value[0],
     month: (parseInt(value[1], 16) - 1), // Month is zero based in Date() object, so you need to subtract 1 to get proper month number
     year: value[2],
     hours: value[3],
     minutes: value[4],
     seconds: value[5]
    }

    // Assign individual values to Date object
    //   new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
    var date = new Date(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hours, d.minutes, d.seconds);
    var days = parseInt(Limit, 10);
     if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
       date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

       d = 
       {
        day: date.getDate(),
      month: date.getMonth() + 1,
      year: date.getFullYear(),
      hours: date.getHours(),
      minutes: date.getMinutes(),
      seconds: date.getSeconds()
       }

     var newDate = 
      checkTime(d.day) + '-' +
      checkTime(d.month) + '-' + 
      d.year + ' ' + 
      checkTime(d.hours) + ':' + 
      checkTime(d.minutes) + ':' + 
      checkTime(d.seconds);
     
     document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML='Expiration Date: ';
     document.getElementById('ExpDate').innerHTML += newDate;
     }
   });

   function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <label class="control-label" for="Name">Release Date </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" readonly id="Date" name="txtFecha" placeholder="Release Date" 
          value="02-06-2019 16:19:01" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="control-label" for="Name">Time Limit<span style="font-size: 150%;  color: red;">*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <select class="form-control" id="Limit" name="cbmlimit" readonly required> 
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">0 days</option>
    <option value="8">8 days</option>
    <option value="15">15 days</option>
    <option value="30">30 days</option>
    <option value="45">45 days</option>
    <option value="60">60 days</option>
    <option value="90">90 days</option>
  </select>
  <label class="control-label" id="ExpDate" for="Name">Expiration Date:</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed. But the date `02-06-2019 16:19:01` is 'dd/mm/yyyy' format. Is there a way to format the date?

Comment: @Roly I updated my answer to output to `MM-DD-YYY HH:MM:SS` format!

Comment: Thanks for your help. the date `02-06-2019 16:19:01` is June 2nd 2019 not February 6th 2019. In the updated code, if I select 8 days the result says `2-14-2019 16:19:01` or February 14th 2019. And it should be `10-06-2019`

Comment: @Roly updated my answer again, this should be what you are looking for now :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

my idea you need [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for help your issue

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentDate = moment();  // set 'release date' with moment.js
  $('#Date').val(currentDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
  var lb = $('#ExpDate');
 $('#Limit').on('change', function () {
      var Limit = $(this).val();
      lb.html(Limit);
      currentDate = moment();
      var adding = currentDate.add(Number(Limit), 'days'); // adding day(s)
      $('#Date').val(adding.format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")); // set to input.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="alert row">
<div class="col-lg-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="Name">Release Date </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" readonly id="Date" name="txtFecha" placeholder="Release Date" 
  value="02-06-2019 16:19:01" type="text">
</div>
 
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <label class="control-label" for="Name">Time Limit<span style="font-size: 150%;  color: red;">*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="Limit" name="cbmlimit" readonly required> 
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="0">0 days</option>
      <option value="8">8 days</option>
      <option value="15">15 days</option>
      <option value="30">30 days</option>
      <option value="45">45 days</option>
      <option value="60">60 days</option>
      <option value="90">90 days</option>
  </select>
    <label class="control-label" for="Name">
      Expiration Date: add
      <span id="ExpDate"></span>
      days to date on ExpDate
    </label>
 </div>
 </div>
```